# Automapper Map lists with layered properties

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm having some trouble mapping an object with multiple layers of properties to an object with a single layer of properties. Here's an example:

My destination class

```
public class Part
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public IList<Part> ReplacedBy { get; set; } = new List<Part>();

}
```

My source classes

```
public class PartType
{
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public PartInformationType Part { get; set; }

}

public class PartInformationType
{
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<PartType> ReplacedBy { get; set; } = new List<PartType>();

}
```

Note that the real objects have ALOT more properties in each layer so it would be a hassle to do a ForMember() on each affected property. Is there any automated way to do this for me?

---

Expected result:
This is giving me the expected result but only for one generation of parts, say that each replacedBy part is replaced by another part for 10 generations, that quickly becomes unmanageable

```
var part = Mapper.DynamicMap<Part>(result);
part.ReplacedBy = new List<ReplacementPart>();
foreach (var partType in result.ReplacedBy)
{
    var replacementPart = Mapper.DynamicMap<ReplacementPart(partType.Part);
    replacementPart.Name= partType.Name;
    replacementPart.Position= partType.Position;
    part.ReplacedBy.Add(replacementPart);
}
```

Comment: Automapper maps by some conventions - like variable name, so if you have property `Name` in source and destination object- you won't need to specify mapping configuration for it - it will just work.

Comment: When i debug and check the ReplacedBy objects everything is null except PartNumber

Comment: What does your usage look like? I assume you are trying to map two sources to one destination, if that is the case, then you need to pass the first partially mapped object into the second mapping.

Comment: I've added an example to the post  with the result i want to achieve.

Comment: You can use the default flattening. Like [this](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/904b4d6ed3ab38581df0a1a93939aae7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an interesting problem, and I happen to have solved a very similar one recently in one of my projects so hopefully my answer will suit your needs as well or at least get you going on the right track. I've adjusted the sample code somewhat to your case.

My destination model class (pretty much same as yours):

```
public class PartModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public List<PartModel> ReplacedBy { get; set; }
}
```

My two source classes (also pretty much same as yours)

```
public class PartEntity
{
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public PartEntityInformation PartEntityInformation { get; set; }
}

public class PartEntityInformation
{
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PartEntity> ReplacedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I have defined a static `EntityMap` with the configurations for my two mappings. As I have mentioned in the comments of your question - I am not specifying any particular member mapping config as Automapper will just map by convention because the property names match between my source and destination objects.

```
public static class EntityMap
{
    public static IMapper EntityMapper { get; set; }

    static EntityMap()
    {
        EntityMapper = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<PartEntity, PartModel>();
            config.CreateMap<PartEntityInformation, PartModel>();
        }).CreateMapper();
    }
}
```

You can use `EntityMap` like below. Nothing special here, it will just yield me the base model where only `PartNumber` property is mapped.

```
        var rootPart = GetPart();
        var rootPartModel = EntityMap.EntityMapper.Map<PartModel>(rootPart);
```

In order to get the nested mappings for your `ReplacedBy` parts, you can use recursion (this is how I solved this nested mapping requirement in my project, there may be better solutions). In this method, I recursively map the nested child objects to their destination objects because the initial mapping will give me the number of items that there is in the nested `ReplacedBy` list.

```
    public static void MapRecursively(PartModel partModel, PartEntity partEntity)
    {
        EntityMap.EntityMapper.Map(partEntity.PartEntityInformation, partModel);

        if (partEntity.PartEntityInformation.ReplacedBy == null
            || partEntity.PartEntityInformation.ReplacedBy.Count == 0) return;

        for (var i = 0; i < partModel.ReplacedBy.Count; i++)
        {
            MapRecursively(partModel.ReplacedBy[i], partEntity.PartEntityInformation.ReplacedBy[i]);
        }
    }
```

So you can now just use the `rootPart` and `rootPartModel` with this recursive method to map out of the rest of your nested objects.

```
        MapRecursively(rootPartModel, rootPart);
```

This should work out of the box, I have provided the `GetRootPart()` method specification below as it is just the sample data I have used.

```
   private static PartEntity GetPart()
    {
        var partEntityInfo = new PartEntityInformation
        {
            Name = "SomeName",
            Position = "2",
            ReplacedBy = new List<PartEntity>
            {
                new PartEntity
                {
                    PartNumber = "22",
                    PartEntityInformation = new PartEntityInformation
                    {
                        Name = "SomeSubName"
                    }
                },
                new PartEntity
                {
                    PartNumber = "33",
                    PartEntityInformation = new PartEntityInformation
                    {
                        Name = "33SubName",
                        Position = "33SubPosition",
                        ReplacedBy = new List<PartEntity>
                        {
                            new PartEntity
                            {
                                PartNumber = "444",
                                PartEntityInformation = new PartEntityInformation
                                {
                                    Name = "444SubSubname"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        };
        var part = new PartEntity
        {
            PartNumber = "1",
            PartEntityInformation = partEntityInfo
        };
        return part;
    }
```